# Whats the most secure way I can use python-ldap in my script to connect to my ldap server?

Tags: python-2.7, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I have a script that is using the python-ldap module.

Here is my basic code that makes a connection to my ldap server:

```
server = 'ldap://example.com'
dn = 'uid=user1,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com'
pw = "password!"

con = ldap.initialize(server)

con.start_tls_s()
con.simple_bind_s(dn,pw)
```

This works...but does the actual literal password have to be stored in the variable `pw`?? it seems like a bad idea to have a password stored right there in a script.

Is there a way to make a secure connection to my ldap server without needing to store my actual password in the script??

Comment: It is possible, I would suggest taking a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072946/python-ldap-is-it-possible-to-bind-without-explicitly-writing-the-password

Answer (score 0):

Placing the password in a separate file with restricted permissions is pretty much it. You can for example source that file from the main script:

```
. /usr/local/etc/secret-password-here
```

You could also restrict the permissions of the main script so that only authorized persons can execute it, but it's probably better to do as you suggest and store only the password itself in a restricted file. That way you can allow inspection of the code itself (without sensitive secrets), version-control and copy around the script more easily, etc...